# Sub domain URL slash / missing after domain and before Post & page slug

Tags: htaccess

WordPress page/page is not working after moved the file to subdirectory. URL structure domain.com/subdirectory/post1 is loading as domain.com/subdirectorypost1 - slash (/) is missing before post/page slug. Home page and Other site assets working fine (i.e., images, css, js) - Only post and pages not loading.

Site .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /subdomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have updated different permalink and still, it's not working. Also, deactivate all plugins and tested them, still no fix. Someone, please help me to fix it.

Comment: What you describe is a **subdirectory**, not a "subdomain". How have you defined the `siteurl` and `home` values?

Comment: Updated both siteurl and homepage with - http://domain.com/subdirectory/